# JAX-RS serialize only few properties

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

We have a DTO like below

```
public class Student {
    private String name;
    private String id;
    private ExamResults results;
    private Address residentialAddress;
    private Address permanentAddress;
    // setter and getter methods
}
```

The same DTO is used by multiple endpoints like student/details/{studId}, student/details/{studId}/results

In student/details/{studId} endpoint we dont populate `results` property. But still it is being returned as null in the response.

Similarly, in student/details/{studId}/results we dont populate `permanentAddress` and `residentialAddress`, but still these are being returned as null in the response.

Basically, I would like to control what properties are serialized based on the endpoint irrespective of whether they are null or not.

Thanks.

Comment: have a look at JsonSerializer or ContextResolver. One example here http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/private_fields_serialization_with_json

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Student {
```

Comment: This annotation is from jackson and will work only if the underlying JAX-RS implementation uses jackson internally. Since the underlying implementation is different for different app servers, the solution might not work.

Comment: But in fact you are responsible for libraries-management (build tools: maven, gradle, ant etc). Application server won't change it.

Comment: We would not like to manage jaxrs libraries and would like to use the default application server's implementation.

Comment: Sorry, I have edited my question. I would like to control what properties are serialized irrespective of whether they are null or not.

Comment: In this case you can try to write custom JsonSerializer<Student> and implement all rules. (Jackson)